# CSS works locally but not on Dev server

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a page that displays a ticket number from a ticketing system.  When the page loads it generates a ticket number and displays this number in a label.  It also dynamically adds a cssclass to the label based on the ticket that is generated.  This works fine locally but when I upload it to the dev server the cssclass does not show.  There is another item on the same aspx page that has a cssclass added on the front end and it is displaying fine.  I looked at the yiew source from the page from the dev server and it appears the class gets added fine on the backend.

Here is the aspx:

```
<table width="300">
    <tr>
        <td class="ItemTxt">Customer Track Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <p>The customer track number is: </p>
            <p style="text-align:center"><asp:Label ID="lblTrackNum" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="greenTicketColor"></asp:Label></p>
            <p>Click OK to continue and return to the Lobby Dash.</p>

            <p><asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" onclick="btnOK_Click" /></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
enter code here
```

Here is the codebehind

```
private void DisplayTicketNumber(string sTicketNumber)
    {
        string sTrackColor = sTicketNumber.Substring(0, 1);
        switch (sTrackColor)
        {
            case "G":
                lblTrackNum.CssClass = "greenTicketColor";
                break;
            case "R":
                lblTrackNum.CssClass = "redTicketColor";
                break;
            case "B":
                lblTrackNum.CssClass = "blueTicketColor";
                break;
            case "M":
                lblTrackNum.CssClass = "maoTicketColor";
                break;
            case "V":
                lblTrackNum.CssClass = "vandeTicketColor";
                break;
            case "A":
                lblTrackNum.CssClass = "afipTicketColor";
                break;
            case "E":
                lblTrackNum.CssClass = "ebtTicketColor";
                break;
            case "Q":
                lblTrackNum.CssClass = "qaTicketColor";
                break;
            case "F":
                lblTrackNum.CssClass = "fhTicketColor";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        lblTrackNum.Text = sTicketNumber;
    }
```

Here is the CSS

```
    .greenTicketColor
{
    color: #007F00;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.redTicketColor
{
    color: #DF0000;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.blueTicketColor
{
    color: #0065CB;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.maoTicketColor
{
    color: #959595;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.vandeTicketColor
{
    color: #7f007f;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.afipTicketColor
{
    color: #00cbfd;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.ebtTicketColor
{
    color: #fd98cb;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.qaTicketColor
{
    color: #cbfdcb;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fhTicketColor
{
    color: #fdfd00;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is the view source from the page displayed from server.  Notice it shows the class correctly added.

```
<table width="300">
<tr>
    <td class="ItemTxt">Customer Track Number</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left">
        <p>The customer track number is: </p>
        <p style="text-align:center"><span id="MainContent_lblTrackNum" class="blueTicketColor">B6</span></p>
        <p>Click OK to continue and return to the Lobby Dash.</p>

        <p><input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnOK" value="OK" id="MainContent_btnOK" /></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks for the responses. I know the easiest thing is the reference to the css file. If you look at this line the style is showing correctly:

```
<td class="ItemTxt">Customer Track Number</td>
```

The line of code above is on the aspx page. The style that is being added in the codebehind is not displaying. Here's my head content. This is from a Master Page. Don't know if that matters..

```
<head runat="server"> 
<title>FAST Tracker</title> 
<link href="~/Styles/FastTrackStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"> 
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
</head>
```

Comment: can you add the code where you are referencing your css file? the simpliest answer is that somehow your css file is not included.

Comment: if you are using firebug/dragonfly or similar stuff you can also check if your css file is requested by browser

Comment: Please include your html `<head>` code, namely the code referencing your CSS file. The problem is probably being caused by the file not being included in the publish or, most likely, the path is not correct.

Comment: Does anyone out there have an idea on how to correct this issue???

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have uploaded for CSS file to the Server and are referencing it correctly.  If you use FireBug or view the source of your HTML page when its running on the Dev server can you navigate to the css file by clicking the URL in the  tag

Comment: Yes I am positive that I uploaded the css file.  If you look in the first <td> of the table there is a cssclass="ItemTxt" that is displaying correctly.  The only difference in the 2 cssclass in that table are one is applied on the aspx page, the other (not working) is applied in the C# code behind page.  I have not used FireBug but I can navigate to css file on Dev server.

Comment: No caching caching happening anywhere? Memcached?

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is usually not case sensitive, but servers ARE.
Check your paths (case sensitive)...

Comment: I tripple checked all paths.  The reference to the css is in a master page and the css is working everywhere except this one instance.  The only difference is this one instance the css is being added in the codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the resolution for me was to make sure the virtual directory permissions are setup properly, otherwise the CSS and images won't show.

You can usually right click on another web application in IIS to see the permissions to reference for your web application.